# Add Utility with Bootstrap 5 Utility API

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I moved my utilities map merge code around the file in every place I could think of and it still doesn't work. Tried putting the bootstrap import in at the end since people say that should help and it still doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
// Configuration
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/functions";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/variables";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/maps";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/mixins";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/utilities";

// Layout & components
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/root";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/reboot";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/type";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/images";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/containers";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/grid";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/tables";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/forms";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/buttons";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/transitions";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/dropdown";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/button-group";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/nav";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/navbar";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/card";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/accordion";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/pagination";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/badge";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/alert";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/progress";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/list-group";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/close";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/toasts";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/modal";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/tooltip";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/popover";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/carousel";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/spinners";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/offcanvas";
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/placeholders";

// Helpers
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/helpers";

// Utilities
@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/utilities/api";

$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities,
    (
        "c-mr": (
            property: margin-right,
            values: (
                0: 0rem,
                1: 0.25rem,
                2: 0.5rem,
                3: 1rem,
                4: 1.5rem,
                5: 3rem,
            ),
        ),
    )
);

@import "../../../bootstrap-5/scss/bootstrap";
```